# .NET + Connection to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, .net

Recently, our developers have increased the Pool size in all connection strings to 8000. They are using VS 2010 Framework 4.0. In the DB side I am monitoring that up to 4000 connections is opening. But the problem is we have tones of error logs (see below) hand-shake time-out problems.

For me it is a very wired problem and I could not find any clue. I know with the server that I have (real monster) we are able to support more connections opened. I know Max is 32767, but I never expect to reach this number, but four kilo is far less.

Connection Strings :

```
connectionString 1 ="server=S1;database=DB1;Integrated Security=false; user id=user; Password=password; Min Pool Size=10; Max Pool Size=8000; Connect Timeout=5;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
.
.
.
connectionString 10 ="server=S1;database=DB10;Integrated Security=false; user id=user; Password=password; Min Pool Size=10; Max Pool Size=8000; Connect Timeout=5;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And the error Log :

> GXMT.Common.DataGateway.DAOException: Executed command:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Connection Timeout Expired.  The
>   timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection
>   could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login
>   process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to
>   create multiple active connections.  The duration spent while
>   attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login]
>   initialization=1; handshake=3565; [Login] initialization=0;
>   authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=1001;  --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Thanks.

PS : New discovery is when the number of connection exceed 4000, even in Sql Server Management Studio opening a connection takes around 25 seconds. !?

Comment: What kinds of waits are you seeing in sys.dm_os_wait_stats? I've got a hunch that it's THREADPOOL, and could be fixed by increasing Maximum worker threads.

Comment: What are the general specs on the target server (OS, CPU, RAM, disk, SQL Edition)?  Is there only one client connecting to the server?

Comment: Also, it's a long shot, but have you checked `select * from sys.configurations where name = 'user connections'`?  This is the server-side limit, which appears to be set to 32767 by default, but could have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You've like got a developer that's not closing the connections and causing connection pool growth.  Periodically recycle the connection pool or try using a sql trace to identify when new connections are created so you can identify and fix the problem code.